# PostgreSQL - Set Encoding, Collations and CType to 'Windows-1252'

Tags: postgresql, special-characters, diacritics, windows-1252

I am trying to create a database and then a table that support special french accent characters. After trying UTF-8, I saw that special accent characters do not appear in my database, they appear only as normal latin characters.

So I did some research and found out that the correct encoding should be [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), an encoding that supports special accent characters.

I have been trying to implement this encoding inside my PostgreSQL database but without success. The results remain the same, as if they were UTF-8 encoded. I do not know how to write the correct Collation anc Ctype values for 'WIN1252' encoding.

This is what I have been doing:

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template0';

\c template0

UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = FALSE WHERE datname = 'template1';

DROP DATABASE template1;

CREATE DATABASE template1 WITH owner=postgres ENCODING = 'WIN2512' TEMPLATE template0;

UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template1';

\c template1

UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = FALSE WHERE datname = 'template0';

CREATE DATABASE test_database2 WITH OWNER postgres ENCODING 'WIN1252' TEMPLATE template1;

\c test_database2;

CREATE TABLE locations (locations VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO locations VALUES ('Franche-Comté');
INSERT INTO locations VALUES ('Midi-Pyrénées');
INSERT INTO locations VALUES ('Provence-Alpes-Côte d Azur');
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `client_encoding` to WIN1252 and keep the database encoding to utf8;

---

```
DROP DATABASE compte ;
CREATE DATABASE compte WITH encoding = 'utf8' ;

\c compte;

SET client_encoding = WIN1252;

CREATE TABLE locations (locations VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO locations VALUES ('Franche-Comté')
                        , ('Midi-Pyrénées')
                        , ('Provence-Alpes-Côte d Azur');

SELECT * FROM locations;
```

---

You could also set the client_encoding for the entire database to cp1252 (when connecting, the clients can always overrule this)

(You can check the encoding by dumping to an *ascii* file and hexdumping that)

---

```
ALTER DATABASE compte
        SET client_encoding = WIN1252;

-- copy locations TO '/tmp/locations.tsv' ;
```

---

If you want to create the database with a specific collation you need to specify that when creating it, and use `template0` (or via a specially prepared `template_XXX`. The collation type **must exist** when creating the database.

you can list available collations by (connecting to template1 and) using `\dOS+` in the psql terminal.
[ I could not find `fr_fr.utf8` in my installation]

---

```
DROP DATABASE compte ;
CREATE DATABASE compte WITH
        TEMPLATE = template0
        encoding = 'utf8'
        LC_COLLATE = 'en_CA.utf8'
        LC_CTYPE = 'en_CA.utf8'
        ;
```

Comment: Please see my addition. The point is: the terminal has its own idea about which encoding to assume. This should **match** the client_encoding setting at the database side.

Comment: As a result, my hexdump contained *double* encoded characters:, Compte ended in `c3 83 c2 a9` . (that was caused by lying to the DBMS: my client actually used unicode encoding when supplying the `VALUES` for the insert)